# Inverse formula for a function inside an integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lagrange-inversion

If I know that
$$\int_0^\infty g(x)a^xdx=\frac{1}{{(2^c-a^c)}^{{b}/{c}}}$$
where $a\in [0,1]$ and $b$ and $c$ are fixed constant. Is it possible to get the expression for $g(x)$?

Comment: Certainly, there is no reason to think $g$ is unique.

Comment: Looks like a Laplace transform to me - and there is an inverse.

Comment: Is that true for all $a$ and some $b$ and $c$ that depend on $a$, or a particular set of values of $a,b,c$?

Comment: It would be better to change variable; let $t=-\log a$, so that $t\in (0, \infty)$ and the integral reads $$\int_0^\infty g(x)e^{-xt}\, dx, $$ which is the one-sided Laplace transform of $g$.

Answer (score 6):

$$
\int_0^\infty g(x)a^xdx=\frac{1}{{(2^c-a^c)}^{{b}/{c}}}
$$
Set $\displaystyle{g(x) = a^{-x}{ke^{-kx}\over{(2^c-a^c)}^{{b}/{c}}}}$

The integral becomes

$$
\int^\infty_0{ke^{-kx}\over{(2^c-a^c)}^{{b}/{c}}}dx={1\over{(2^c-a^c)}^{{b}/{c}}}
$$

Since we can set any value for $k$ in $g(x)$, we can't expect for a unique solution

As Thomas Andrews said, in general, you can substitute any function $f(x)$ for $g(x)$ such that
$$g(x)=f(x){a^{-x} 
\over{(2^c-a^c)}^{{b}/{c}}
}$$
where
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=1
$$

Comment: Or you can use any $f$ with $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=1$ instead if $ke^{-kx},$ of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The expression of g doesn't coincide with the Laplace's antitransformation of the function $\frac{1}{(2^c-a^c)^{\frac{b}{c}}}$? Is this correct?

Comment: @m91c a special case would be using the Dirac delta distribution, letting $g(x)=\delta (x)k$ where you can set $k$ as $\frac{1}{(2^c-a^c)^{\frac{b}{c}}}
$, in fact you can also set $g(x)=h(x)\delta(x)k$ as long as $h(0)=1$, so I wouldn't say that the inverse Laplace as you've said, coincide